# How do I prevent having to log in on 3 separate prompts every time I start my machine?

Tags: login, prompt, seahorse

Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal, Ubuntu Classic desktop

Each time I start my machine, I have to log in 3 times. I spent a week in IRC>Freenode>#ubuntu and got nothing but condescension. I've searched on the official Ubuntu fora for similar problems, tried every recommendation, and still get 3 login screens. As a workaround, I have reset login such that I get a login screen at startup, which I'd prefer not to get since this machine is accessible by no one but me, physically.

I have gone into System > Preferences > Passwords and Encryption Keys, set first 'Passwords: default' to 'Default' and unlocked it, and unlocked the 'Passwords: login' key, too. Next, since that changed nothing, I set 'Passwords: login' to 'Default', and checked to make sure it was still unlocked. Again, no change, still get 3 login prompts at startup.

I've checked twice to insure that I am the owner of the files; I am.

At the suggestion of several people in #ubuntu, I've deleted first one, then the other password key in 'Passwords and Encryption Keys'. Still get 3 login prompts.

I changed from the Unity desktop to Ubuntu Classic. While that didn't fix the above problem, it is a much more elegant desktop than Unity, and I'll keep it.

From what I've read, this seems to be a Seahorse issue, but beyond that, no one seems to have a solution that works.

I'm lost. This shouldn't be this difficult or annoying. I'm trying to help our local Old Time music collective get their machines switched over to Ubuntu in order to save them some money which they can use to promote their DRM-free music. But from what I've seen of Ubuntu so far on my own machine, I can't really recommend that they make this switch. I hope to be proved wrong on that point. But as it stands, if I was out of town or out of country and they ran into a problem, they'd have no way of fixing it as they're all less experienced than even I am. I'm not trying to cast aspersions on Ubuntu or Linux, but it seems pretty clear that KNOWLEDGEABLE, HELPFUL support for Ubuntu is lacking barring any desire on the problem-experiencing-user's part to avoid condescension. Having worked with, and run, several non-profits over the past 20 years, I know that getting volunteers to act professionally can be like herding cats. But an organization's reputation can be denigrated by sarcastic behaviors on the part of those who serve, effectively, as its public face.

Thank you all for your help and support.

Now...does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

**1** - Go to **Passwords And Encryption Keys**

**2** - On there you have the opportunity to change your default password, enter your old password and then in the field where you would put your new password press **Enter**

*By pressing Enter you have submitted a blank password, meaning that you will no longer be asked for it upon logging on to your computer.*

To stop being asked for your password when you Log Out & Log In again go to **Users And Groups** click on **Change Password** and then tick the box labelled **Don't Ask For Password On Login**

Comment: This solution was offered in the Ubuntu fora and I tried it. When I did that, I simply got 3 password prompts on which I had to click 'Submit'to log in.

Comment: Okay, go to Password And Encryption Keys, right click and delete the password key.  Now restart the PC and see if that does the trick.

Comment: "At the suggestion of several people in #ubuntu, I've deleted first one, then the other password key in 'Passwords and Encryption Keys'. Still get 3 login prompts."

Comment: Sorry, that was an incomplete answer. As I indicated above, I tried that, too. The end result was that I had to sign into each website or application separately...twice. Once when I would get a prompt from Seahorse, and then again on the actual website, or in the actual application.

Comment: That was one of the first suggestions offered about a week and a half ago, and while it seems logical, it doesn't prevent getting 3 prompts, anyway.